# Why do polylines digitised disapper when I save the layer. Would the shapefiles be corrupt?

Tags: shapefile, qgis-2.2

I have a problem with QGIS 2.2. When I digitise a polyline layer and save the edits the lines disappear from the map. This does not happen for the polygons in the same GIS project. The points are still present in the attribute table.

Also related problem with the lines which have been categroised to show different symobology do not display with the different symbology

I have never had this problem before. Could the files be corrupt?

Comment: Do all the features show up if the layer is not categorized?

Comment: I suggest to update to the latest QGIS version 2.16. There have been lots of bus fixed in more than 2 years since QGIS 2.2 was published.